# Using fs.writeFileSync on Ubuntu getting Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, permissions, discord.js, filesystems

My code:

```
fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', 'hello world');
```

This works fine on windows, but on ubuntu, I keep getting this: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'file.txt'

How do I get past this error and allow permissions to my project so it can write a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide write permission to your directory.
following is the link of that:
https://askubuntu.com/q/402980

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo node index.js` instade of `node index.js`.